# How to add parameters to a React object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, styles

I have a shared style with error:

```
export const modalStyle(height)= {  // <-- Whats the syntax for adding parameter here?
    width:MODAL_WIDTH,
    height:height,
    backgroundColor:color_theme_light.mainGreen,
    borderRadius:22,
    justifyContent:"center",
    alignItems:"center",
    
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 1,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.20,
    shadowRadius: 1.41,
    elevation: 2
}
```

How can I add a parameter to it, so when I call this style I can change the height dynamically?

```
import {modalStyle} from './modalStyles'

<View style={modalStyle(40)}>
 ...
</View>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you are having two common ways to declare and export the `modalStyle` function.

**Function declaration:**

```js
export function modalStyle(height) ({})
```

**Arrow function:**

```js
export const modalStyle = (height) => ({})
```

Comment: I still got errors: Expression excepted

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a copy of your error?

Comment: I was missing the ().. :D this works! export const modalStyle = (height) => ({})